# Keep ios keyboard open

Tags: ios, uiwebview, keyboard

I have a ios app that launch a UIWebView and you can interact with this web (the app is like a container). In the interaction with the web you need the keyboard a lot. So, I want (if it's possible) to keep the keyboard always open.

I've found some solutions, but none of them work for me.

I've tried with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

and I able to detect when the keyboard are going to hide, but I don't know what I can do in keyboardDidHide method to avoid the keyboard to be closed.

I've tried also with:

```
webView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction
```

But nothing happens.

Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try playing with `UIViewController's` `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` property.  Try overriding this property and returning `NO`.

Comment: Well the method ask for disable and you return no, so it means that you keep the automatic dismissal, you should instead return true.